# "Join an activity" or "join in an activity"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

Is there any difference between *join* and *join in* when talking about starting to take part in an actvity. For example:

> Many sacrificed their weekend to join (**in**) the hunt for the missing girl.
>
> He stared at them without joining (**in**) the conversation.

I am confused because as this [dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/join) says *join* means  to begin to take part in an activity that other people are involved in, and [*join in*](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/join-in) means to take part in something that a group of people are doing or that someone else does. Aren't they are the same and *in* is optional?

Comment: ***To join in*** can be seen as a "phrasal verb" meaning (and *syntactically equivalent to*) ***to participate***. And since we need to include a preposition with, for example, *I will participate **in** the conversation,* it's also possible to ***repeat*** the preposition when using the phrasal verb form. It might look a bit odd in print (especially to nns! :), but most native speakers wouldn't think there was anything particularly unusual about the ***spoken*** form of [*Not joining **in in** the funny conversations.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22joining+in+in+the+funny%22)

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot get it. Is the preposition "in" optional?

Comment: Approximately, ***in*** is "optional", yes. The (potential) difference between *You should join [**in**] the conversation* with or without the preposition is so small it would rarely be significant. But there's also the question of whether ***in*** is part of the phrasal verb (to join in) or part of a prepositional phrase *following* the verb (single-word ***or*** "phrasal"). Note that ***both*** usages can occur simultaneously, as in the previous example, and also [*Peppi joined **in in** the same strain*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22peppi+joined+in+in%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***To join in*** is a "phrasal verb" meaning (and syntactically equivalent to) ***to participate***. And since we need to include a preposition anyway in, for example, *I will participate **in** the conversation*, if we directly replace ***participate*** by ***join in***, we arrive at the superficially "curious" repetition...

> 1: *I will join **in in** the conversation* - my example
>    2: *Not joining **in in** the funny conversations* - a real example from [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22joining+in+in+the+funny%22)
>     3: *Peppi joined **in in** the same strain* - another [real example](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22peppi+joined+in+in%22)

...which occurs a lot more often in speech than you might think from looking at written corpuses (to native speakers, it ***looks*** stranger than it sounds, so they're less likely to *write* it).

---

The (potential) difference between *You should join [**in**] the conversation* with or without the preposition is so small it would rarely be significant. To the extent that there ***is*** a difference, it's that *joining **in*** implies being more ***actively, deeply*** involved "in" something (which simply reflects and amplifies the ***literal*** meaning of ***in*** as it relates to "container" metaphoric usages like this).

Because the prepositions are serving two different *purposes*, it's perfectly possible to have both the phrasal verb ***and*** the preposition-based adverbial clause in the same utterance.